# In forest (tikz) for syntax trees, how do I create an arc above one node separating it off from the rest of the tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0fr4.png)'s a picture example of what I want:

[image]

I'm able to make the type of arc that I want with this command:

```
\draw (-2,-2) [black,thick,dashed,domain=45:180] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)}) ;
```

But it always creates the arc at the very top of the tree, even when I put the command inside the tree in the node where I want the arc. Here's the code I'm using:

```
begin{forest}
[TP [T\textsuperscript{0}]
[vP [DP\textsubscript{???},circle,draw]
[v' [v\textsuperscript{0}]
[VP,tikz={\draw[black,thick,dashed,domain=45:180] (2,2) plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)}) ;}
[V\textsuperscript{0}] [DP\textsubscript{???},circle,draw]
]]]]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimla document with the code you are currently using for the tree?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: My mistake, this is my first time on this site and I didn't even think to read the posting guidelines. I've added my code to the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `name=` key to name some reference node(s) and then use an `arc` path to draw the arc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[TP 
  [T\textsuperscript{0}]
  [vP 
    [DP\textsubscript{???},circle,draw]
    [v' 
      [v\textsuperscript{0}]
      [VP
        [V\textsuperscript{0},name=left] 
        [DP\textsubscript{???},circle,draw]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[double] 
  ([xshift=-12pt]left) arc[start angle=180,end angle=60,radius=2cm];
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I apologize for not including the code that I was working with. I'll be sure to not forget that when I post any other questions in the future.