# How to draw a curve to indicate syntactic domain in the qtree?

Tags: linguistics, syntax, tikz-qtree, qtree

How to draw a curved line in the qtree and add a description like the following picture?

```
\Tree [.n,v,aP [.n,v,a ] [.$\sqrt{P}$ [.$\sqrt{\alpha}$ ] [.$\sqrt{\beta}$ ] ] ]
```

[image: https://minio.scielo.br/documentstore/2175-8026/dT6twcHBBKBCXgYCz5T9nZH/d187117b34a83367a42f7c6059d36e14c85bd856.png]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a code fragment, it's better to put your fragment into a compilable document that people can play with. `qtree` is a very old package and I wouldn't recommend using it. What you want to do is much easier using `tikz-qtree` or `forest`.   Especially if you are just starting out drawing trees, I would definitely recommend learning to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! May I know if I should use gb4e or other packages for linguistic glossing? It seems that gb4e generates many bugs but I'm not sure if there is any good alternative.

Comment: Personally I use `gb4e` and I'm not aware of any real bugs, although it has some quirks.  Most can probably be solved by adding  `\noautomath` after you load the package. If your glossing needs are very complex, then `expex` is a good alternative, but it's very non-latex in its syntax since the author is a plain TeX user.

Answer (score 4):

Using `forest` or `tikz-qtree` is definitely the way to go for trees. I would recommend `forest` since it allows you to name nodes very simply which then allows all sorts of annotations of the sort you need to be made quite simply. `tikz-qtree` can do the same sort of thing, but you need to encode the nodes specifically in the tree, which makes the code much more clunky.

Here's both solutions, using the answer here:

- [In forest (tikz) for syntax trees, how do I create an arc above one node separating it off from the rest of the tree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164429/2693)

And here's another couple of solutions, also using `forest`:

- [Regarding drawing phase boundaries on syntactic trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401399/2693)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.n,v,aP [.n,v,a ] [.$\sqrt{P}$ [.\node (A){$\sqrt{\alpha}$};] [.$\sqrt{\beta}$ ] ] ] 
\draw 
  ([xshift=-14pt]A) arc[start angle=180,end angle=60,radius=2cm] node[below] {Spellout domain};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{forest}
[{n,v,aP} [{n,v,a} ] [$\sqrt{P}$ [$\sqrt{\alpha}$,name=A] [$\sqrt{\beta}$ ] ] ]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-14pt]A) arc[start angle=180,end angle=60,radius=2cm] node[below] {Spellout domain};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I vote your post and delete my answer. +1